# Preposition for conversion to another unit

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should be used when I want to say a value in a different measure unit? For example, what is a correct preposition in the following sentence?

> Twelve miles? I have no idea how far that is. What is it __ kilometres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a bit on the verb. Often you use "in"

> What is 12 miles in kilometres?
>
> (answer: about 19 km)

But with "change" you say "Please change 12 miles to kilometres" or "into kilometres".

Comment: I would never use to but into works.

Comment: @Paul Childs: **to** and **into** are both used by many tens of millions of native speakers in that kind of construction.  Both work.